# How do I get my WebView to play embedded videos even if the application is minimized?

Tags: android, video, webview, webkit, playback

I want to make my WebView continue to play embedded YouTube videos even if the application is minimized.

I have tried many methods but I continue with the error, that when I minimize the application the video playback of yotube stops.

In conclusion I want to make YouTube videos continue to play even if the application is minimized

> This is my MainActivity code

```
package com.network.shwr.sherwarezmusic;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.webkit.CookieSyncManager;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.webkit.CookieManager;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.WebView);
        webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webview.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        webview.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
        webview.getSettings().setAllowContentAccess(true);
        webview.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        webview.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        webview.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
        webview.getSettings().setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(true);
        webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        webview.loadUrl("https://www.music.sherwarez.ml/");

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
            // Handle the camera action
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }

    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url){
        CookieSyncManager.getInstance().sync();
        URL url1 = null;
        try {
            url1 = new URL(url);
        }
        catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("C sharp corner user Ref " + url1.getRef());
        System.out.println(" C sharp corner user host " + url1.getHost());
        System.out.println("C sharp corner user authority " + url1.getAuthority());
        String cookies = CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(url);
        System.out.println("All COOKIES " + cookies);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"All Cookies " + cookies , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```